# Function with ggplot2 (ordered barplot): Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I got an error concerning environments in `R` but I don't know how to solve it. I would like to create a function which plots an ordered barplot using `ggplot2`. Ordered means that the feature with highest count will be plotted on position 1 and the feature with least counts will be at the last position (decreasing order).

This is my function:

```
plotBarPlot <- function(result) {

    result <- table(result)
    result <- sort(result)
    df <- data.frame(num = result)
    rn <- rownames(df)
    rn <- factor(rn, levels = rn)
    gg <- ggplot(data = df, aes(rn, df$num))
    ##gg <- ggplot(data = df, aes(reorder(rownames(df), df$num), df$num))
    gg <- gg + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    gg <- gg + ylab("counts") + xlab("")
    gg <- gg + coord_flip()
    return(gg)
}
```

The error I get is `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'rn' not found`.
Try

```
result <- c(rep("red", 3), rep("blue", 5), rep("green", 10), rep("yellow", 2))
plotBarPlot(result)
```

The commented line in the function reorders the factors (this gives the ordered barplot at the end), it gives the same result (when running in `.GlobalEnv` as the two lines above it).

Running the body of the function outside of the function gives the ordered barplot, but if `rn` and `df` is removed from `.GlobalEnv` the error is raised.

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: What’s the point of prefixing all the variables with `.`?

Comment: No special point, I will remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slightly modify your function:

```
plotBarPlot <- function(result) {
    df <- as.data.frame(table(result))
    df <- df[with(df, order(Freq)),]
    df$result <- with(df, factor(result, levels = result))
    gg <- ggplot(data = df, aes(result, Freq)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
          ylab("counts") + 
          xlab("") + 
          coord_flip()
    print(gg)
}

result <- c(rep("red", 3), rep("blue", 5), rep("green", 10), rep("yellow", 2))
plotBarPlot(result)
```

[image]

Comment: This creates for me a non-ordered graph (yellow, red, green, blue instead of green, blue, red, yellow)

Comment: Ordered in the sense that green has most of the counts and yellow least. This is the intention of the function!

Comment: The comments shouldn't sound aggresive, sorry! Thanks, now it works!